# DataStore code I created is erroring even though I did it correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, datastore

I tried this to create a Data Store to save users input. Anyway, I followed all the steps but some parts are red.

I implemented the necesssery dependencies. This is what I tried. The snippets surrounded with stars are red in Android Studio.

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.stringPreferencesKey
import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStore
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import java.util.prefs.Preferences
import androidx.datastore.core.Preferences


class StoreUserInput(private val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by **preferencesDataStore("FirstName")**
        val FIRST_NAME_KEY = stringPreferencesKey("first_name")

    }

    val getFirstName: Flow<String?> = context.dataStore.data
        .map {
            preferences ->
            **preferences[FIRST_NAME_KEY]** ?: ""
        }

     suspend fun saveFirstName(name: String) {
        context.dataStore.**edit** { **preferences** ->
            preferences[FIRST_NAME_KEY] = name
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove type from `Context.datastore`

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.edit
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.stringPreferencesKey
import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStore
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map


class StoreUserInput(private val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("FirstName")
        val FIRST_NAME_KEY = stringPreferencesKey("first_name")

    }

    val getFirstName: Flow<String?> = context.dataStore.data
        .map {
                preferences ->
            preferences[FIRST_NAME_KEY] ?: ""
        }

    suspend fun saveFirstName(name: String) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[FIRST_NAME_KEY] = name
        }
    }

}
```

Follow official documentations for implementation https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-datastore/tree/preferences_datastore